# PyTesseract OCR poor result on Documents

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using PyTesseract for OCR. Here are my images:

[image]:

[image]

And the code I'm using for OCR:

```
def pre_process(img):
"""Apply preprocessing to an image"""
   angle = getSkewAngle(img)
   img = rotateImage(img, -1.0 * angle)
   img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
   return thresh

def get_text_from_image(path):
   """Retrieve text data from image"""
   img = cv2.imread(path)

   img = pre_process(img)

   text = tess.image_to_string(
      img, lang='eng', config='--psm 6 --oem 3'
   ) 

   get_text_from_image(path)
```

How can I improve my OCR results? I tried different `psm`s, different threshold kernel options, differend arguments to `threshold` , but no success. I read that Tesseract performs better on DPI > 300, but not sure what's the point of DPI in this case, since I'm using `opencv`. The thing is I don't know what kind of documents I will get as an input. It might be any types of documents, so I a good balanced arguments and methods in my code, so that it could perform equally good with any document types. Also, image extensions might be scanned `pdfs`, `jpg` or `png` files.

Here are the OCR results:

`````
---------------------------------------FIRST IMAGE----------------------------------------------
‘ “\1yos/e7 11:03 813. 884 0863 LORILLARD TAMPA +++ GREENSBOR_ _——@ 002/003
Retail Excel Progress Report

Submission for: Distribution by/to:

July 34 (3 OM to RSM 1st of Month

August29 () To: BW. Caldarella RSM to RW.C. 40th

September 30 ( ) ce: 0.0.8.

October 31 (X) From: Kent B. Mills

Nevember 28 ( )

December 30 ( ) Area: § Reglon: 17

Acceptance/Response: What is the retailers response to Lorillard's Excel

Merchandising pian?

Payment” was not In glace. The chains where we were using the "Flex Payment”

system we have not heen as successful. The P.O.S, requirements of the P-1 Plan

ith OIC nies is. diff tai
Independents:
it PA ising Is bei

Addith . . g Zia fighting PM Exc! PM/RUR

Hardware Evaluation/Effectiveness; Comment on the assembly of displays and

application of shields:

The displays are easily assembled and durable. Some questions have been raised

sanceming the inahility to be flush with the counter and/or up against the register.

Pennanant Advertising Evaluation/Effectiveness/Acceptance: (P-U/P-5 & C-5 |

Plans Only:

vai og

eR co
nN
nN
on
eal
Cc
t=


-----------------------------------SECOND IMAGE-----------------------------------------------

@@ BRITISH

@@ COUNCIL
Questions 36—40
Complete the summary below.

Choose NO MORE THAN TWO WORDS from the passage for each answer.

Write your answers in boxes 36-40 on your answer sheet.

Sobotka argues that big business and users of helium need to help look after helium
stocks because 36 .................... Will not be encouraged through buying and selling
alone. Richardson believes that the 37 .................... needs to be withdrawn, as the
U.S. provides most of the world's helium. He argues that higher costs would mean
people have

38 ..............0:+2+. tO USE the resource many times over.

People should need a 39 .................... to access helium that we still have.
Furthermore, a 40 .................... should ensure that helium is used carefully.
14
````
`````

Comment: please see this [useful tutorial](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

Comment: @Bilal I read this tutorial and applied all the method listed in the tutorial. It didn't help